# Is there a way to make normalized coordinates the default in the UV editor

Tags: uv

I have been doing a lot of UV editing lately and have noticed that I am often enabling normalized coordinates in the UV editor and thought it would be useful to turn this on by default as it means I don't need to care about the resolution of the texture I am working with. However, I can't find a way to set this by default, and even turning it on and saving as the default scene doesn't work. Is there an option hidden away somewhere that would allow me to do this?